# I am not able to create a defect and associate with a userstory. I am using the below rally rest api java code

Tags: rally

I am not able to create a defect and associate with a userstory. I am using the below  rally rest api java code.

```
JsonObject newDefect = new JsonObject();

newDefect.addProperty("Name", "defect added to check");
newDefect.addProperty("Description", "description added to check");
newDefect.addProperty("Requirement", "/userstory/11018012245");
newDefect.addProperty("SubmittedBy", "user/10832575945");
newDefect.addProperty("Workspace", "/workspace/10832575967");
newDefect.addProperty("Project", "project/10832575978");

CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("defect", newDefect);
CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);createResponse.getObject().get("FormattedID").toString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine, it would appear that you've just got some missing "/'s" on a couple of your ref's:

`newDefect.addProperty("SubmittedBy", "user/10832575945");`

-->

`newDefect.addProperty("SubmittedBy", "/user/10832575945");`

`newDefect.addProperty("Project", "project/10832575978");`

-->

`newDefect.addProperty("Project", "/project/10832575978");`